# Need help in installing cx_Oracle on Pivotal cloud foundry (PCF).

Tags: python, cx-oracle, pcf

Have few python scripts and API that I want to deploy to PCF. During build process I get this error and the container is destroyed at the end. **Do you know how to get around this**. Sounds like cx_Oracle needs Oracle client presence.
-----> Installing python-2.7.11
    Downloaded [file:///tmp/buildpacks/3e091922d73fa9260b32ad7737d842e3/dependencies/https___pivotal-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com_concourse-binaries_python_python-2.7.11-linux-x64.tgz]
         $ pip install -r requirements.txt
           Collecting Flask==0.12 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
             Downloading Flask-0.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82kB)
           Collecting cx-Oracle (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
             Downloading cx_Oracle-5.3.tar.gz (129kB)
               Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
               Traceback (most recent call last):
                 File "", line 1, in 
                 File "/tmp/pip-build-8i1use/cx-Oracle/setup.py", line 174, in 
                   raise DistutilsSetupError("cannot locate an Oracle software " \
               distutils.errors.DistutilsSetupError: cannot locate an Oracle software installation

```
           ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-8i1use/cx-Oracle/
```

Answer (score 1):

cx_Oracle is not an option on PCF at this time. You should use JDBC (ojdbc.jar) connection mechanism instead. It's light weight.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, cx_Oracle needs an Oracle client. The instant client, however, is easily deployed. See the download page here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html. Instructions are included at the bottom of the page. You will need either the "Basic" or "Basic Light" package at runtime and the "SDK" package to compile and build.

Comment: I am told installing oracle client on PCF is not an option because o it's size (fat client). I went with ojdbc.jar (JDBC connection) and I deployed the app to PCF successfully. App is up and the API is running. Now I am trouble shooting the execution errors. PCF doesn't give you a good way to see what files are deployed. May it's my enterprise specific restriction (?).

Comment: The smallest you can get an Oracle client is about 30 MB. So if that is too large you're out of luck.